# What is the difference between using In and join in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm going over Stanford's databases course material and I came across this question.

> For three tables  R,S,T  that only have one attribute A :
>
> ```
> R = {1,2,3,4,5}
> S = {1,3,5,7,9}
> T = {1,4,7,10}
> ```
>
> Can you write a query to select  R ∩(S∪T) - in other words elements that are in  R  and either  S  or  T?

I answered

```
SELECT DISTINCT A from R WHERE A in S OR A in T
```

and the solutions was

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.A
FROM R, S, T
WHERE R.A = S.A OR R.A = T.A;
```

Our answers agreed in terms of the results, so I thought my answer was fine.

There was then another question -

```
Now test your query above for the case where  S=∅ - what happens and why?
```

Now I would have thought the answer would be

```
1,4
```

which is what my query spits out.

However, their query spits out nothing.

Why is their answer right and what is the difference between our queries?

Comment: I'd say that "solution" is poor. Modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax is good programming practice. Old style, comma separated, implicit joins should be avoided.

Comment: The syntax you are using for relational algebra is fairly academic, and not often seen/used on this site.  You might want to edit your question to use ANSI SQL instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "right" solution in SQL is pretty well a transcription of the problem statement:

```
SELECT A FROM R
INTERSECT
(
     SELECT A FROM S
     UNION
     SELECT A FROM T
)
```

But to the question in your title, the general difference between `IN` and `JOIN` is that `IN` is part of a *predicate*. It makes an assertion about a result set (in your example using `IN`, the result set we're dealing with is that produced by `FROM R`) but it doesn't *modify* the result set (except by filtering out rows).

In contrast, a `JOIN` *does* modify a result set, in that it adds additional columns to the result set. In your second example, we ended up (via the nasty old comma join syntax) with a result set containing 3 columns. All three columns, unfortunately, share a single name - `A` - and so that's why a *specific* column had to be pulled out in the `SELECT` clause.

---

It does seem that the materials you're studying may be doing you a disservice by freely mixing more mathematical models of databases (using set notation, "attribute") and the less-mathematical SQL language without being clear on where it's blurring the boundaries between the two.

Comment: Hmm what I don't understand though is why their answer is empty. 

If S is now an empty set, then S union T is just T. Which then means the entire statement is R intersection T, which is 1,4. 

Why is it empty?

Comment: @praks5432 - I believe their solution is wrong. From the problem description, your IN based solution works. Their solution *could* be modified to work correctly by using left joins.

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT DISTINCT A from R WHERE A in S OR A in T"

I think (meaning I'm not 100% certain) this is invalid SQL, strictly speaking, because an IN clause in a predicate must be followed by a complete query expression, and "S" or "T" are not complete query expressions.  SELECT A FROM S (/T) are, and you'd probably have to write

"SELECT DISTINCT A from R WHERE A in (SELECT A FROM S) OR A in (SELECT A FROM T)"

"SELECT DISTINCT R.A FROM R, S, T" is obviously wrong, for exactly the reason they point out in the next question.  I say WTF ???????????????.  I don't understand what line of tutoring is being followed when the "given solutions" to exercises are plain wrong and figuring out what exactly is wrong is the next exercise ..........

Note that it may often benefit query performance if you help the optimizer by eliminating disjunctive predicates yourself (this has nothing to do with the correctness of the results/of the query per se) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT A from R WHERE A in (SELECT A FROM S)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT A from R WHERE A in (SELECT A FROM T)
```

EDIT

That would probably have to be

```
SELECT DISTINCT A from R WHERE A in (SELECT A FROM S)
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT A from R WHERE A in (SELECT A FROM T)
```

Comment: When targeting the abstract "SQL" language rather than a specific implementation, there aren't really any universally applicable guidelines for what will or will not help or harm the optimizers ability to produce the best plan. Given that your final query can be mechanically derived from your second query, one would hope that a sufficiently well developed optimizer that would benefit from this transformation would apply it itself.

Comment: sufficiently well developed is the crux.  Disjunctions are nowhere trivial to deal with in optimizers and I suppose you know that.  And it was only intended as a tangential remark.

Comment: And I remember experiments having been mentioned on dbdebunk where several variations of the same -provably equivalent- query yielded differences in execution times of as much as two orders of magnitude, so I wouldn't rely too easily on any optimizer having been "sufficiently well developed".